# TypeScript cannot find name 'NodeJS'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am developing a webApp using [iot-dsa JS sdk](https://github.com/IOT-DSA/sdk-dslink-javascript) angular4 and nodejs. My `app.component.js` looks like:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LinkProvider } from 'dslink';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  link = new LinkProvider(['http://127.0.0.1:8080/conn'],
  'RequesterExample-', {
    isRequester: true,
    isResponder: false
  });

  res = this.link.connect().then(function() {
    return this.link.onRequesterReady;
  }).then(function(requester) {
     // work with requester here  
  });
}
```

While build the code using `ng build` I am getting this error:

`ERROR in node_modules/dslink/dist/dslink.node.d.ts(2,23): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'NodeJS'. Did you mean 'Node'?`

Please let me know if more info is required.

Comment: If you follow the comments in [the source file where the error happens](https://github.com/IOT-DSA/sdk-dslink-javascript/blob/new-sdk/tool/js/node.d.ts), the version used is Node v6. What version of Node are you using?

Comment: @PaulRey am using node v6.12.3

Comment: Given you are using this in Angular (client) - shouldn't you be using the browser version of dslink (/dist/dslink.browser.js)?

Comment: @lwallent how and where should I specify this?

Comment: @humblebee this depends on your build/deployment infrastructure. You should perhaps update your question with some more details.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried options given @ [NodeError](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/320)

Comment: I have been through this link. Not sure if it's a fix as my browser console throws this error:
`set location' called on an object that does not implement interface Window.`